# IPv6 routing failing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dns, ipv6

I am trying to setup a lab IPv6 network, and I am proceeding in the following way.

- I have a device, which needs an IPv6 global address.
- I have configured my Windows-10 laptop to be an access point by using the following:

  ```
  netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=ipv6-hotspot key="12345678"
  netsh wlan start hostednetwork
  ```
- I have dibbler installed for the DHCPv6 server with the following configuration:

  ```
  log-level 7
  log-mode short
  iface "Local Area Connection* 3"
  {
    T1 1800
    T2 2000
    class
    {
     pool 2001:db8:1111::1-2001:db8:2222::ff
    }
    pd-class
    {
      pd-pool 2001:db8:1122::/48
      pd-length 48
    }

    option dns-server 2001:db8::1, 2001:db8::2 
    option domain ipv6.com, pinger.ipv6.com
  }
  ```
- I do NOT have a DNS server installed on the system - not sure how to use the Windows DNS server.
- The hosted network is over WLAN - my subnet uses only Wi-Fi devices.

I am able to get prefixes (DHCPv6 Prefix Delegation works) and an IPv6 address for my device.

However:

when I do a `ping -6 2001:db8:1111:0100:0000:0000:0000:0004` (which I got from the DHCPv6 server for the device) I get the following error:

```
PING: transmit failed. General failure.
```

My ipconfig looks like:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ad12:52ad:e258:8cad%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : ipv6.com
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:db8:218d:5505:5189:27d2:2922:9563
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b4b0:39b1:844b:147b%11
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.173.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 5:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:1038:21db:3f57:fef9
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1038:21db:3f57:fef9%2
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{879E8F32-A273-4DE5-A08B-16AEC97153A9}:
```

My `route print -6` gives me:

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 22...34 e6 d7 23 65 97 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I218-LM
  7...a0 a8 cd 76 26 f5 ......Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
 10...a0 a8 cd 76 26 f4 ......Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260
 11...a2 a8 cd 76 26 f4 ......Microsoft Hosted Network Virtual Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  2...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
 13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 18...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #4
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  2    306 2001::/32                On-link
  2    306 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:1038:21db:3f57:fef9/128
                                    On-link
 11    281 2001:db8::/48            On-link
 11    281 2001:db8:218d:5505:5189:27d2:2922:9563/128
                                    On-link
 10    266 fe80::/64                On-link
 11    281 fe80::/64                On-link
  2    306 fe80::/64                On-link
  2    306 fe80::1038:21db:3f57:fef9/128
                                    On-link
 10    266 fe80::ad12:52ad:e258:8cad/128
                                    On-link
 11    281 fe80::b4b0:39b1:844b:147b/128
                                    On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
 10    266 ff00::/8                 On-link
 11    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
  2    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  0 4294967295 2001:db8::/48            On-link
===========================================================================
```

A `ping -6` to the link local address of my node on the subnet WORKS.
However, the ping to the provided global IPv6 address does NOT work.

Could someone help me here? Note, I am turning off Windows Defender for the `Local Connection* 3` interface.

Comment: Since you pasted everything else already, could you also put the real address instead of the silly `<ipv6_address>` censoring?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You can freely edit your own posts but for your protection, this must be done under the original user account.  It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Comment: what was the answer?